# QuickSort an array without modifying it (may not use a temporary array) in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, linked-list, quicksort

normally I would never ask my school exercise on stackoverflow but I think what they want from us is impossible without using temporary array or modifying the array.

What they want from us is:

1. QuickSort Function which should be recursive
2. It should sort(that is what sorting algorithms do lol) but it should leave the array intact,
3. may not use temporary array
4. and it has to return the sorted list in a linkedlist format.
5. Function should be like this:

`LinkedList *quickSort(int *array, int startPosition, int endPosition)`

Returning as linkedlist is easy, sorting is easy but without modyfying in everystep of the algorithm? I dont think so.

**I am not saying please send me the solution. I only want you to answer this, is not it impossible?**

Edit: By "Leaving the array intact" teacher meant "dont change the size of the array, but you can modify the order of the array", so problem solved

I will check one of the answers just to make tag question as solved.

Comment: Perhaps by "temporary array" they mean an array in addition to the one which will be returned? I agree that the wording seems odd. I would ask for clarification.

Comment: Couldn't you just copy the array into the list to be created and then use quicksort on that list?
I don't see anything prohibiting you from modifying the returned list.

Comment: Can you modify and then restore the initial array ?

Comment: But the function returns a simple LinkedList using struct, not an array.

Comment: Pretty sure "_Clarify my homework_" is off topic or too broad or something. You should really ask your teacher.

Comment: @Kaiserludi nope because the function takes an array as parameter not a LinkedList

Comment: @Jarod42 I think without using temporary array you cant restore the array. And doing that in recursive function seems impossible.

Comment: @Eralp: What function are you talking about?

Comment: Those requirements sound weird, but there are only two ways of doing this. Either you copy the array into a linked list container first and quicksort that (pretty dumb, but follows the requirements to the letter), or you build a linked list _with pointers into the array_. Which you can then sort with Quicksort without ever modifying the array. Your teacher probably meant the latter. Or well, of course you could have an array of objects with an intrusive linked list... but I don't think they'll want that.

Comment: Isn't this question just testing for knowledge of by-reference vs by-value?  If you pass the array into a recursive function by value, it necessarily will not modify the original array and does not need a temporary array.  You'll run out of stack space pretty quickly if you pull this crap, but it fulfils the requirements, does it not?

Comment: @Kaiserludi I should clarify that sorry, edited question. Whole quicksort thing must be just a function and should return LinkedList pointer

Comment: the fact it returns a pointer suggests that I'm on the wrong track with my by-value assumption.  I strongly suggest you have this discussion with your teacher, who has access to much more context than we do.

Comment: You have requested a one-word answer (yes or no), and "yes" doesn't actually help you solving the problem. Questions like this do not fit here as they are not helpful for others.

Comment: @n.m. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Perhaps try rewording it so that the question and the answers are more useful for other readers.

Comment: @Chris:
When you pass the array by value, the compiler will create a temporary copy, so that approach is clearly not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I thought I was missing something and there is a way which I dont know, after your comments I called the assistant and he said **of course you need to modify the array, you would not be able to do without modifying it.** But in the exercise declarations it clearly says

b) sorts the numbers in the sub-array of the array between the given positions using quick sort algorithm 
**and leaving the array intact** (may NOT use a temporary array)

Again thanks for all the answers and comments. Sorry for the missunderstanding guys.

Comment: I had been thinking about this, and I think perhaps there was an error on the question wording. I believe when they said "intact" they probably meant "in place".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: A quick sort can be done in place (without any temporary storage areas.)

Since I don't want to complete your homework for you directly :) Here is a resource to get you going.

See the second algorithm at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort

Comment: But it modifies the array does not it?

"if left ≤ right"
"swap array[left] with array[right]"
here it modifies the array.

Comment: I think in the context of a homework question that probably means that it remains a static block of memory. Obviously it is illogical if you cannot modify the contents, or copy them elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the question, `quickSort` can be defined as

```
std::list<int> quickSort(int * array, int startPosition, int endPosition) {
    std::list<int> result;
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= endPosition; ++i)
        result.push_back(array[i]);
    QuiskSort(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

where `QuickSort` has the definition

```
template <class Iterator>
inline void QuickSort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    if (end <= begin) return;
    Iterator pivot = begin, middle = begin + 1;
    for (Iterator i = begin + 1; i < end; ++i) {
        if (*i < *pivot) {
            std::iter_swap(i, middle);
            ++middle;
        }
    }
    std::iter_swap(begin, middle - 1);
    QuickSort(begin, middle - 1);
    QuickSort(middle, end);
}
```